Is there a way to achieve this result of wrapping text with a background using HTML/CSS?
I want to recreate this effect of wrapping some text with a background using HTML/CSS. Is that possible? Any pointing to the right direction would be of great help.
Wanted effect
I already tried stacking text-containers with rounded corner div's on top of each other, but this does not give the best result. Result I got. See code for the result I got


body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.text-container:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}

.text-container:nth-child(2) {
  top: 67px;
}

.text-container:nth-child(3) {
  top: 134px;
}
<body>
  <div class="text-container">
    Hello please work pretty please
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    Hello please work pretty
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    Hello please work pretty please please please
  </div>
</body>




Voting to re-open— the user is asking how to achieve word wrap, not add a background to the text (the background is already present in the code they provided).

Although the given response was not useful, the question was asked before



body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.highlight-text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff7f50, #ff6347);
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  text-align: center;
}
<body>
  <div class="highlight-text">
    Hello, please work pretty please!
  </div>
</body>



